# WPF DataGrid, Template Column and Virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created VM classes for the `DataGrid` items (Rows and Cells).
The VM class for Cell is shown below:

```
public class ListGridCell : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public ListGridCell(string Name)
    {
        // Init properties
        this.Name = Name;
        this.DataValue = null;
        this.DataEditor = null;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private object _DataValue;
    public object DataValue
    {
        get { return _DataValue; }
        set { _DataValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DataValue"); }
    }

    private FrameworkElement _DataEditor;
    public FrameworkElement DataEditor
    {
        get { return _DataEditor; }
        set { _DataEditor = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DataEditor"); }
    }
    ...
}
```

`DataGrid` columns and VM is built totally dynamically from code.
I create template column (`DataGridTemplateColumn`) and set the `CellTemplate` to the followind template (illustrated through XAML):

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataValue}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=DataEditor}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Everything works fine and as expected when `DataGrid` is initially filled and shown.
Now, If I try to SCROLL the grid the following exception occurs:

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element.
>   Disconnect it first.

This exception has something to do with grid's row virtualization and binding `Content` to `DataEditor` inside cell template. If I turn off the row virtualization, everything works fine but grid performance becomes very bad so it is not an option.

Do you know `DataGrid` virtualization works behind the scenes, what happens when row is loaded/unloaded and what could be causing this error?
Are there any workarounds?

*Note: I cannot use `ContentTemplate` binding for cell data editor in cell template (which is suggested in many places as workaround) because I MUST manually create and initialize this cell editor.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

This is obviously a bug somewhere in `ContentControl` when using `Content` binding in combination with `DataGrid` virtualization.

Once I switched to `ContentPresenter` everything works flawlessly.

Working cell template is:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataValue}" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DataEditor}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Possibly this bug still exists in Windows Store XAML but without the error, see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797231/content-lost-contentcontrol-bound-to-usercontrol-inside-virtualizing-stackpanel#tabs